# TypeScript intellisense doesn't seem to resolve default module in CJS context

Tags: node.js, typescript, cjs

Let's say I have the following basic CJS module:

```js
module.exports = { foo: "bar" }
```

For which I've configured separately following TS typing:

```js
declare const test: { foo: string };

export default test;
```

Having that when I try to import this typed module in TypeScript file, Intellisense works as expected:

[image: TS intellisense]

But when I try to require it in CJS module intellisense fails, as it suggests the `.default` property, on which then `foo` is suggested, which is not correct:

[image: CJS intellisense]

What I'm missing in TS setup to have intellisense in CJS working properly? Is it possible to make it right?

Comment: Perhaps you need to disable esModuleInterop?